# Python trading signal NameError

Tags: python, pandas, function, finance, algorithmic-trading

Ichimoku Kinko Hyo or Ichimoku is not just a strategy, but a full trading system. It builds on price bars to generate its signals. Developed around the late 1930’s by Goichi Hosoda, the system grew to be widely popular in Japan and other locations around the world.

```
def ichimoku_kinko_hyo(Data):
  # Tenkan-sen (Conversion Line): (9-period high + 9-period low)/2))
  nine_period_high = Data['High'].rolling(window= 9).max()
  nine_period_low = Data['Low'].rolling(window= 9).min()
  Data['tenkan_sen'] = (nine_period_high + nine_period_low) /2
  tenkan_sen= Data['tenkan_sen']
  
  # Kijun-sen (Base Line): (26-period high + 26-period low)/2))
  period26_high = Data['High'].rolling(window=26).max()
  period26_low = Data['Low'].rolling(window=26).min()
  Data['kijun_sen'] = (period26_high + period26_low) / 2
  kijun_sen= Data['kijun_sen']
  # Senkou Span A (Leading Span A): (Conversion Line + Base Line)/2))
  Data['senkou_span_a'] = ((Data['tenkan_sen'] + Data['kijun_sen']) / 2).shift(26)
  senkou_span_a= Data['senkou_span_a']

  # Senkou Span B (Leading Span B): (52-period high + 52-period low)/2))
  period52_high = Data['High'].rolling(window=52).max()
  period52_low = Data['Low'].rolling(window=52).min()
  Data['senkou_span_b'] = ((period52_high + period52_low) / 2).shift(26)
  senkou_span_b= Data['senkou_span_b']
  # The most current closing price plotted 26 time periods behind (optional)
  Data['chikou_span'] = Data['Close'].shift(-26)
  chikou_span= Data['chikou_span']

  return Data
 
#our Dataset of "ethereum" downloaded from Yahoo Finance
ETH = pd.read_csv("ETH-USD.csv",index_col="Date", parse_dates=True)

ichimoku_kinko_hyo(ETH)

def signal(Data, buy, sell):
for i in range(len(Data)):
        if Data[i, tenkan_column] > Data[i, kijun_column] and Data[i - 1, tenkan_column] < Data[i - 1, kijun_column] and \
           Data[i, closing_price_column] > Data[i, senkou_span_a_column] and Data[i, closing_price_column] > Data[i, senkou_span_b_column] and \
           Data[i - 26, chikou_column] > Data[i - 26, closing_price_column]:
               Data[i, buy] = 1
 
        if Data[i, tenkan_column] < Data[i, kijun_column] and Data[i - 1, tenkan_column] > Data[i - 1, kijun_column] and \
           Data[i, closing_price_column] < Data[i, senkou_span_a_column] and Data[i, closing_price_column] < Data[i, senkou_span_b_column] and \
           Data[i - 26, chikou_column] < Data[i - 26, closing_price_column]:
               Data[i, sell] = -1
# The tenkan_column is the index of the Tenkan-Sen Column
# The kijun_column is the index of the Kijun-Sen Column
# The senkou_span_a_column is the index of the Senkou-Span A Column
# The senkou_span_b_column is the index of the Senkou-Span B Column
# The chikou_column is the index of the Chikou-Span Column
# The closing_price_column is the index of the Close Column
    

Here are the conditions of a trade based on the Ichimoku system, followed by the signal function that tells Python to print 1 in case a bullish signal is generated and to print -1 in case a bearish signal is generated.
Go long (Buy): Whenever the Tenkan-sen crosses the Kijun-sen from the below to the above while the market price is above the Ichimoku cloud. And finally, the Chikou span’s last value must be higher than the corresponding market price in the same point in time.
Go short (Sell): Whenever the Tenkan-sen crosses the Kijun-sen from the above to the below while the market price is below the Ichimoku cloud. And finally, the Chikou span’s last value must be lower than the corresponding market price in the same point in time.



  ichimoku_kinko_hyo(ETH)

        signal(ETH)
```

my question is about how to solve this keyError I am getting
I'll be super greatful if someone could help me!

here's my Dataset head if you wonder:

```
Date        Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close   Volume              
2021-02-22  1935.557861 1936.453735 1580.626587 1781.992920 1781.992920 42409646036
2021-02-23  1781.409058 1781.409058 1378.840942 1570.203979 1570.203979 52029864713
2021-02-24  1571.476440 1710.983765 1511.018921 1626.575684 1626.575684 31329000537
2021-02-25  1625.393921 1670.224121 1465.058960 1475.703735 1475.703735 24481681873
2021-02-26  1478.653320 1559.028931 1407.979248 1446.033691 1446.033691 31435997881
```

Comment: What key error do you get?  Which line, exactly?

Comment: It's certainly true that `Data[i-26, chikou_column]` is going to fail if there are less than 26 rows, and probably does not do what you expect even if there are.

Comment: NameError: name 'tenkan_sen' is not defined

Comment: it's more than 6000 column

Comment: When I run your data, `ichimoku_kinko_hyo` runs without error and does add columns to the dataframe (they all contain NaN, probably because there aren't enough rows for the rolling window).  `signal` failed with `tenkan_column` not defined.  If I set `tenkan_column = 'tenkan_sen'`, then I get KeyError for `(0, 'tenkan_sen')`.  Is that what you see?

Comment: yes exactly!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do row/column references by using `Data[i, tenkan_column]`.  Pandas has different rules for indexing than numpy.  What that does is try to use the tuple `(0, "tenkan_sen")` as an index.

You can do row indexing by row number using the `iloc` member.  So, this works:

```
print(ETH.iloc[0][tenkan_column])
```

However, you are immediately going to run into trouble with this:

```
        if Data[i, tenkan_column] > Data[i, kijun_column] and Data[i - 1, tenkan_column] < Data[i - 1, kijun_column] and \
```

Even if we change that to:

```
        if Data.iloc[i][tenkan_column] > Data.iloc[i][kijun_column] and Data.iloc[i - 1][tenkan_column] < Data.iloc[i - 1][kijun_column] and \
```

during your first iteration, `i` will be zero, so you'll try to use `Data.iloc[-1]`, and there is no row -1.  If you need to compare this row to the previous row, you'll have to start at row 1.  However, even that is going to explode when we get to:

```
            Data.iloc[i - 26][chikou_column]...
```

If you really need to refer to the previous 26 rows, then you will have to start with row number 26.

Comment: Can I have the full code format?

Comment: No, this is not a code-writing service.  Only you know what you're trying to do with the `i-26` stuff.  You have to decide how you will handle the first 25 rows.